# Código considerado apenas em tempo de compilação pode conter Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++

Ao projetar uma função que some dois valores de classes distintas quaisquer, posso escrever o seguinte de forma genérica:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
decltype((*(T*)0) + (*(U*)0)) add(T t, U u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

A parte interessante é o tipo de retorno: `decltype((*(T*)0) + (*(U*)0))`. Em outras palavras: "O tipo resultante da soma de um objeto do tipo `T` com um do tipo `U`".

Mas para obter um objeto do tipo `T`, uso `(*(T*)0)` que, embora seja inválido se executado, resulta sempre no tipo `T`. Uma outra forma de chegar no mesmo resultado seria assim: `T() + U()`. O problema é que assim fica assumido que existe um construtor padrão para os tipos, mesmo que eu nem precise de um construtor para a função.

Minha dúvida é: escrever essa função é realmente permitido e não cria Undefined Behaviour?

De forma mais geral, posso utilizar expressões que resultam em Undefined Behaviour quando executadas, mas que tem um tipo bem definido, dentro de um `decltype`?

---

Nota: No C++11 é possível escrever:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

E no C++14 é possível escrever:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

Mas isso não é relevante para a pergunta.

Comment: Excelente pergunta. Eu chutaria que não criaria um comportamento indefinido mas não saberia fundamentar, só sei que se o código consegue ser gerado adequadamente e não ter indefinição, qual o problema? De fato vou pesquisar sobre isto. Mas alguma coisa me diz que você é quem poderá dar a melhor resposta aqui :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar qualquer expressão válida dentro do decltype. E não importa se caso a instrução fosse executada seu comportamento seria indefinido. Isso porque o decltype não executa a expressão e então utiliza o tipo resultante. Ao invés disso ela infere o tipo resultante a partir da expressão.

No caso do seu exemplo, ele não derreferencia o ponteiro nulo pra descobrir o tipo. Ele sabe que a derreferenciação de um ponteiro de T é um valor de tipo T.

Até porque, não tem como a expressão ser executada, já que, como você mesmo disse, isso é tudo feito em tempo de  compilação.